# JQuery script problem in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I made a script which works in all browsers, except for SOME Internet Explorer's. I cannot seem to figure out why some Internet Explorer's work, and others don't. At the office, 4 Internet Explorer 8's @ version 8.0.6001.18702 work perfectly while 4 others Internet Explorer's 8 @ version 8.0.6001.18702 (so completely the same browsers) are not working. We all have Windows XP and all the latest updates.

Please visit http://www.stardekk.be/voorontwerp/verco/ with Firefox, safari, chrome, ... and afterwards with Internet Explorer (7, 8, doesn't matter).

The problem lays within the top of the website. The thumbs should have an overlay, and when hovered; the overlay should go away and a tooltip should come up.

I hope someone can help me since 50% of the Internet Explorer's work, and 50% don't.

Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$("#gallery div img").after('<div class="overlay"></div>');
$(".overlay").css("position", "absolute");
$(".overlay").css("z-index", "30");
$(".overlay").css("background", "url('images/overlay.png')");
$(".overlay").css("top", "0");
$(".overlay").css("left", "0");
$(".overlay").css("width", "241px");
$(".overlay").css("height", "146px");

var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

if ($.browser.msie) {
    $('.overlay').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0, function() { $(this).css("background", "transparent") });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().css("background", "url('images/overlay.png')").fadeTo("fast", 0.8);

    });
} else { 
    $('.overlay').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0, function() { $(this).css("background", "transparent") });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().css("background", "url('images/overlay.png')").fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Off-topic, but you can (and should) combine those seven `$(".overlay").css(...);` calls into a single call passing in an object with the keys; you're making the browser work **way** harder than it needs to. See `.css(map)` here: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Comment: another off-topic suggestion, if the only difference between the ie & firefox versions is the .8 & 1 in the fadeTo, have `var trans = $.browser.msie ? 0.8 : 1;` then use `trans` in the call to `fadeTo`

Comment: Thanks for that; i'll keep that in mind! But i first need to find the problem..

Answer (score 2):

Try using the document [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, or it's shorthand version, instead of the window load event to wrap your code.

```
 $(function() {
    ...
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i tried that already and it doesn't help. Also, i use window.load this time because otherwise Chrome has a problem with document ready!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that all the identical browsers are running in the same compatibility mode? Using the Developer Tools the browser can be configured to use different rendering engines. The options are...

- IE7
- IE8
- IE8 Compatibility View.

Comment: Yes, i quadruple checked compatibility settings. All had IE8 - IE8, or IE7 - IE7 and none had IE8/IE7 - Compatibility view.

Answer (score 0):

New code (with tips)

```
$(window).load(function() {
$("#gallery div img").after('<div class="overlay"></div>');
$(".overlay").css({"position":"absolute", "z-index": "30", "background": "url('images/overlay.png')", "top": "0", "left": "0", "width": "241px", "height": "146px"});

var trans = $.browser.msie ? 0.8 : 1;

$('.overlay').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0, function() { $(this).css("background", "transparent") });
},
function() {
    $(this).stop().css("background", "url('images/overlay.png')").fadeTo("fast", trans);

});
});
```